# How can I construct this Regular Expression

Tags: regex, passwords

Well, have to do a regex for a password.

The password should be 5 UPPERCASE and 3 NUMBERS (Can be in any order) and a total of 8 (5+3)

I try this

```
^(.*?(A-Z){5})(.*\d){3}
```

But not work in any order.

Hope you guys can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, try this:

```
^(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){5})(?=(?:.*\d){3})[A-Z0-9]{8}$
```

Comment: Works perfect, but i would like to know why is there a ":" :)

Comment: @user3306573: `(?:....)` is a non-capture group, see: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^(?=(.*[A-Z]){5})(?=(.*\d){3}).{8}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Wu90rEZmDG2JW_do)

Explanation:

- `^` start at the beginning of the string
- `(?=...)` Look forward, but don't "move" forward yet
- `(?:.*[A-Z]){5}` Match only if the string contains 5 uppercase letters. The `(?:` means "don't capture this group; the `.*` means "allow for characters between the letters."
- `(?=...)` Look forward, but don't "move" forward yet
- `(?:.*\d){3}` Match only if the string contains 3 digits. The `(?:` means "don't capture this group; the `.*` means "allow for characters between the digits."
- `.{8}` match exactly 8 characters
- `$` match the end of the string

Examples:

- Matches:

  - ABCDE123
  - A1J4KLZ8
  - 1ABCDE23
- Non-matches

  - ABCDEF12 (too many letters)
  - ABCD1234 (too many numbers)
  - ABCDE1234 (too many characters)

Comment: Whow!, thats is a good explanation, Hope to be like you guys in some time.

Answer (score 0):

Requiring such stuff for passwords is not a good thing, thus you do not need that regex.

If you look at all possible 8 char passwords, these are much more than all possible 8char 5upercaseletters 3digits passwords.

So, if an attacker knows your requirements (which are maybe rather documented than secret), he can brute-force a password quicker than without these requirements - as he has less password candidates to try.

8 chars without restriction (digits, upper, lower, extra) = (10 + 26 + 26 + x) ^ 8 possibilities

compute yourself how much possible passwords you have. :D

Comment: Yes, but this is for a intranet of maybe 10 peoples, that´s why the requerements, of course if I made a webside with a login form on a WEB  i will put like req Upper, lower number etc.. Thanks for the comment! :)